# Time limit with the "ms" package

Tags: javascript, time, bots, discord, discord.js

```
let giveawayDuration = response2.first();

// Limit duration to max 15d
            if (giveawayDuration > ms('15d')) {
                const l1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#ff0000')
                .setDescription(❌ Your duration cannot be more than 15 Days!)
                return message.channel.send(l1);
            }
```

It whyever blocks every duration, someone knows why/what I have done wrong?

const ms = require('ms');

const response2 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1 });

Comment: You'll need to show the definition of the `ms()` function and what `response2` is.

Comment: edited it, ms is a very very popular package it's just so that you don't have to write 129000000

Comment: but i edited it

Comment: Does `response2.first()` really return a number?

Comment: i mean it returns the content of the msg so for ex "10d" and because it is ms('15d') it should work

Comment: So `giveawayDuration` is "10d" and `ms('15d')` is 129000000, so your comparison is `"10d" > 129000000`?

Comment: yes so if it it is less than 15d the bot will ignore the "if" but if the duration is more than 15d it should execute the "if", but it executeds the "if" even if the duration is less than 15d

Comment: figured it out myself, but thanks for the help, and cause of you comparision i understood it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make it : "ms(giveawayDuration.content) > ms('15d')"